Configuring container registry in dockerized gitlab 17 omnibus with an external nginx
As title said, I'm facing some difficoulties configuring the container registry in omnibus gitlab 17 using an external nginx.
This is the part of my compose.yml relative to gitlab config:
environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        registry_external_url 'https://registry.dinasolutions.cloud'
        gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
        gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = 'registry.domain.tld'
        registry_nginx['enable'] = false
        registry['enable'] = true
        registry['registry_http_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:5000"

this is the nginx config relative to registry.domain.tld
upstream gitlab-registry {
  server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {

  listen *:80;
  server_name registry.domain.tld;
  server_tokens off;
  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/registry.domain.tld/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/registry.domain.tld/error.log;
}

server {

  listen *:443 ssl http2;
  server_name registry.domain.tld;
  server_tokens off;
  
  client_max_body_size 0;
  chunked_transfer_encoding on;
  
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSV1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  location / {
    
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-registry$request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location /v2/ {

    add_header 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version' 'registry/2.0' always;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-registry;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
  }
}

Calling  docker login registry.domain.tld result in a 502 error Bad Gateway.
I'm pretty sure it's a configuration problem, if someone could point me in the right direction i'll really appreciate.
Thanks
Luca

I don't believe this is a programming question. However, to debug your issue, I'd start by checking whether you can access 127.0.0.1:5000 from the location where nginx is running (if nginx is in a container, you would check inside that container). Also, if gitlab is inside of a container, it should be listening on all interfaces inside that container, not just the loopback interface.
